# Is there a way to disable a Firefox extension with AutoHotkey?

Tags: firefox-extensions, autohotkey

I would love to be able to do that with Vimium. That would be a big productivity booster.

Comment: I'm sure you mean `booster`, not `buster`, right?

Comment: lol, absolutely